# Php form is not adding data to my database

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I have this form which is meant to take in user input then once submit is pressed it stores the values in the database. For some reason upon pressing submit the user is redirected to the view page but the data is not inserted in the database.

**Here is the Add Record Code:**

```
 <?php
    /*
        Allows the user to both create new records and edit existing records
    */

    // connect to the database
    include("connection.php");

    // creates the new/edit record form
    // since this form is used multiple times in this file, I have made it a function that is easily    reusable
    function renderForm($memberID = '', $username = '', $password ='', $firstname ='', $lastname ='', $address ='', $email ='', $error = '')
    { ?>
        <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
        <html>
            <head>  
                <title>
                <?php if ($memberID != '') { echo "Edit Record"; } else { echo "New Record"; } ?>
                </title>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h1><?php if ($memberID != '') { echo "Edit Record"; } else { echo "New Record"; } ?></h1>
                <?php if ($error != '') {
                    echo "<div style='padding:4px; border:1px solmemberID red; color:red'>" . $error
                        . "</div>";
                } ?>

                <form action= ""  method="post">
                <div>
                    <?php if ($memberID != '') { ?>
                        <input type="hidden" name="memberID" value="<?php echo $memberID; ?>" />
                        <p>MemberID: <?php echo $memberID; ?></p>
                    <?php } ?>

                    <strong>Username: *</strong> <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>"/><br/>
                    <strong>Password: *</strong> <input type="password" name="password" value="<?php echo $password; ?>"/><br/>
                    <strong>First Name: *</strong> <input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $firstname; ?>"/><br/>
                    <strong>Last Name: *</strong> <input type="text" name="lastname" value="<?php echo $lastname; ?>"/><br/>
                    <strong>Address: *</strong> <input type="text" name="address" value="<?php echo $address; ?>"/><br/>
                    <strong>Email: *</strong> <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>"/><br/>
                    <p>* required</p>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
                </div>
                </form>
            </body>
        </html>

    <?php }

        /*

           NEW RECORD

        */
    {
        // if the form's submit button is clicked, we need to process the form
        if (isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            // get the form data
                $username = htmlentities($_POST['username'], ENT_QUOTES);
                $password = htmlentities($_POST['password'], ENT_QUOTES);
                $firstname = htmlentities($_POST['firstname'], ENT_QUOTES);
                $lastname = htmlentities($_POST['lastname'], ENT_QUOTES);
                $address = htmlentities($_POST['address'], ENT_QUOTES);
                $email = htmlentities($_POST['email'], ENT_QUOTES);

            // check that firstname and lastname are both not empty
            if ($username == '' || $password == '' || $firstname == '' || $lastname == '' || $address == '' || $email == '')
            {
                // if they are empty, show an error message and display the form
                $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';
                    renderForm($username, $password, $firstname, $lastname, $address, $email, $error);
            }
            else
            {
                // insert the new record into the database
                if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT into members (username, password, firstname, lastname, address, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"))
                {
                    $stmt->bind_param($username, $password, $firstname, $lastname, $address, $email, $error, $memberID);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $stmt->close();
                }
                // show an error if the query has an error
                else
                {
                    echo "ERROR: Could not prepare SQL statement.";
                }

                // redirec the user
                header("Location: view.php");
            }

        }
        // if the form hasn't been submitted yet, show the form
        else
        {
            renderForm();
        }
    }

    // close the mysqli connection
    $mysqli->close();

    ?>
```

**Here is the view page:**

```
<!DOCTYDOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
        <head>  
                <title>View Records</title>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        </head>
        <body>

                <h1>View Records</h1>

                <p><b>View All</b> | <a href="view-paginated.php">View Paginated</a></p>

                <?php


                        // connect to the database
                        include('connection.php');

                        // get the records from the database
                        if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM members ORDER BY memberID"))
                        {
                                // display records if there are records to display
                                if ($result->num_rows > 0)
                                {
                                        // display records in a table
                                        echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";

                                        // set table headers
                                        echo "<tr><th>memberID
                                        </th><th>username
                                        </th><th>password
                                        </th><th>firstname
                                        </th><th>lastname
                                        </th><th>address
                                        </th><th>email";

                                        while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
                                        //print "<pre>"; print_r($row); exit;
                                        {
                                                // set up a row for each record
                                                echo "<tr>";
                                                echo "<td>" . $row->memberID . "</td>";
                                                echo "<td>" . $row->username . "</td>";
                                                echo "<td>" . $row->password . "</td>";
                                                echo "<td>" . $row->firstname . "</td>";
                                                echo "<td>" . $row->lastname . "</td>";
                                                echo "<td>" . $row->address . "</td>";
                                                echo "<td>" . $row->email . "</td>";
                                                echo "<td><a href='edit.php?memberID=" . $row->memberID . "'>Edit</a></td>";
                                                echo "<td><a href='delete.php?memberID=" . $row->memberID . "'>Delete</a></td>";
                                                echo "</tr>";
                                        }

                                        echo "</table>";
                                }
                                // if there are no records in the database, display an alert message
                                else
                                {
                                        echo "No results to display!";
                                }
                        }
                        // show an error if there is an issue with the database query
                        else
                        {
                                echo "Error: " . $mysqli->error;
                        }

                        // close database connection
                        $mysqli->close();


                ?>

                <a href="addrecord.php">Add New Record</a>
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: no errors what so ever, the data inserted from the form after clicking submit is not written into the database. 

however when I enter data manually through phpmyadmin everything works correctly and the database records are displayed correctly on my view page

Answer (score 1):

The first error is the bind_param called with incorrect arguments. See the documentation of [mysqli_stmt_bind_param](http://php.net/manual/fr/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

An other error is the number of params to bind required (by the sql query you build with `prepare()` which differs from how many you bind with `bind_param`.

I also suggest you to replace the line `$stmt->***;` to add more error checkpoint

```
$res = $stmt->bind_param(/* correct your code according to the doc :) */);
if (!$res)
  echo 'error when binding params : '.$stmt->error;
else
{
  $res = $stmt->execute();
  if (!$res)
    echo 'error at stmt->execute() '.$stmt->error;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the datatypes like so:

```
$stmt->bind_param("sssssssi", $username, $password, $firstname, $lastname, $address, $email, $error, $memberID);
```

that is assuming all are strings except the id which i assume is integer

Comment: each field in my database is set to varchar

Comment: @MatthewCampana your ID fields are varchar?

Comment: yes. every field is set to varchar

Comment: @MatthewCampana you'll find better performance using Int (depending on total usage of course), not to mention you can auto increment to ensure unique indexes.